# Cordova hook with Gulp : destination files are generated after end of script using cordova serve

Tags: cordova, gulp, hook

I am using Gulp with a cordova project and I added a gulp script using Cordova Hook like this :

```
<hook type="before_serve" src="minification.js" />
```

My problem is that files generated (all.css and all.min.css) are written on disk after "cordova serve" ends. So when this command copy files in "browser" subfolder, they aren't yet here. I suspect pipes in gulp but someone could explain me exacly the reasons?

Here is the code :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var cache = require('gulp-cached');
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');

if (fs.existsSync('./www/css/all.css')) fs.unlinkSync('./www/css/all.css');
if (fs.existsSync('./www/css/all.css.map')) fs.unlinkSync('./www/css/all.css.map');

gulp.task('autoprefixer', function() {
  return gulp.src('./www/css/*.css')
         .pipe(cache('autoprefixer'))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['> 1%','last 2 versions','Firefox ESR','iOS 8']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'));
});


gulp.task('cleanCSS', function() {
  return gulp.src('./www/css/*.css')
        .pipe(cache('cleanCSS'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat('all.css'))
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['autoprefixer', 'cleanCSS']);
gulp.start('default');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this using gulp-cli.

I replaced my code with this :

```
require('child_process').execSync('gulp my_task', {stdio:[0,1,2]});
```

And I created a file gulpfile.js with that code :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var cache = require('gulp-cached');
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');

if (fs.existsSync('./www/css/all.css')) fs.unlinkSync('./www/css/all.css');
if (fs.existsSync('./www/css/all.css.map')) fs.unlinkSync('./www/css/all.css.map');

gulp.task('autoprefixer', function() {
  return gulp.src('./www/css/*.css')
         .pipe(cache('autoprefixer'))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['> 1%','last 2 versions','Firefox ESR','iOS 8']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'));
});


gulp.task('cleanCSS', function() {
  return gulp.src('./www/css/*.css')
        .pipe(cache('cleanCSS'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat('all.css'))
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'));
});

gulp.task('my_task', ['autoprefixer', 'cleanCSS']);
```